# Module based stylesheet import

Tags: angular

I am currently building an Angular website, with multiple stylesheets. A template landing page was added to the project which came with it's own styles. Currently we are importing our global styles in angular.json, which overwrites a lot of the landing page's styles. Is there any way to restrict stylesheets to module or just simply ignore a global stylesheet?

Comment: In angular, each css file is associated with its component by default. If you don't want your global styles to be applied maybe they shouldn't be global. 

To help you better post some config code and app structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use it, you can simply don't import it, on the @component directive, removing the styleUrls

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
```

And will be like that:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-example',
      templateUrl: './example.component.html'
    })
```

Another possible way to deal with it, is to overwrite the global selectors.

And a last way is to use the code bellow:

HTML

```
<div class="component-body">
  <!-- your components html template ... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.component-body{
  all: initial;
  all: unset;
}
```

Comment: Currently the global styles.scss is imported in the angular.json and not individually in components, so I can't simply remove it from a component.

Comment: So import a StyleUrls on your component, overwriting the global css

Comment: Some styles are not overwritten in my other style file, so I want to simply ignore those rules.

Comment: Got it, so I will edit my answer, with a possible solution